# How do I calculate values from multiple textboxes and display in seperate box?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I got 4 textboxes that I want to put values in, and I want it to find the average number from the values of the inputted values to the 4(or more) textboxes.

I want the average to display in a readonly box (is richtextbox good for this?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both a RichTextBox and normal TextBox for this. To ensure that it is read-only, in the designer page do the following;

`Select the TextBox > Scroll under properties window > Behavior Section > Read-Only property`
Setting this property to true will make the TextBox non-editable by the user.

After you have the 4 editable TextBoxes and 1 non-editable, you can implement something like the following to add up the numeric values of TextBoxes and display it in the readonly TextBox.

```
    private void AverageAndDisplay()
    {
        try
        {
            //Convert values to numeric
            decimal one = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
            decimal two = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text);
            decimal three = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox3.Text);
            decimal four = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox4.Text);

            //Find the average
            decimal average = (one + two + three + four) / 4.0m;

            //Show the average, after formatting the number as a two decimal string representation
            textBox5.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}", average);
        }
        catch(Exception e) //Converting to a number from a string can causes errors
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So you should have this steps:

1. Create 4 textboxes. Let's this buttons has ID `Value1Txt`, `Value2Txt`, `Value3Txt`, `Value4Txt`
2. Add button with text *Calculate Average Value*. The ID of the button should be CalculateAverageBtn
3. Add the Label in which you will show the Average. The ID of this Label should be `AverageValueLbl`
4. Attach `OnClick` event on the `CalculateAverageBtn`. You could do it using the signature of the button OnClick="CalculateAverageBtn_Click" or doing it in the code

   ```
   //this should be inside InitializeComponents method
   CalculateAverageBtn.OnClick += CalculateAverageBtn_Click;


   protected void CalculateAverageBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       //...code
   }
   ```
5. Now in the body of CalculateAverageBtn_Click you should Parse the values of the TextBoxes and calculate the average. You could do this using `decimal.TryParse` method

   ```
   decimal value1 = 0;
   if(!decimal.TryParse(Value1Txt.Text, out value1)
   {
       //if you come in this if the parsing of the value is not successful so 
        you need to show error message to the user. This happen when the user 
        enters text like 123Test, this is not a number. So you need to show 
        error message
   }
   ```
6. Create a label in which you will show the error message. Let's call it ErrorLbl. So when the parsing is not successful we will write in this label the error message.

   ```
   if(!decimal.TryParse(Value1Txt.Text, out value1)
   {
       ErrorLbl.Text = "The value of value 1 textbox is not valid number"
       return; //exit the button click method
   }
   ```
7. Calculate the average of 4 textboxes and write it in the `AverageValueLbl`. This should be in button event click

   ```
    AverageValueLbl.Text = (value1+value2+value3+valu4)/4.ToString();
   ```

*Try to understand what you are doing, don't copy/paste mindlessly code. This is pretty much beginner programming. For sure this is homework, so try to understand it because in the future harder homeworks you will be lost.*